# Publish Web service using Visual Studio development server

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio

I have a Web Service that I am trying to publish from VS.
This is the configuration in my project's properties:

[image]

When I try to run the code I get this message:

[image]

It works when I choose Use Local IIS Web Server, but why doesn't it work in the first case as well?

Comment: Which version of VS is it?

Comment: Presumably you have some features/settings that aren't compatible with a VS dev server (such as Windows Authentication with non-anonymous users). Why do you want to use VSDS and not IIS?

Comment: It was the default option and it should work OOB. I'm actually surprised that it doesn't